# Exception when using MEF compose parts

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, mef

I am trying to understand MEF and did a few samples on that. But, when I try to execute this particular code below, I am with an exception.

**ConsoleApplication2.program**

```
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program 
    {
     [Import(typeof(Contracts.IInput))]
     public Contracts.IInput myinterface { get; set; }

    public void Method()
    {
        var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(container );
        Console.WriteLine(myinterface.IsValid());
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new Program();
        obj.Method();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

   }
}
```

I have a separate project for defining an interface.

```
namespace Contracts
{
   public interface IInput
    {
      //All classes that inherit IInput must implement the IsValid Property.
      string IsValid();
    }
}
```

And in another separate project, I use a export class.

```
 using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
 using Contracts;

 namespace Plugin
 {
    [Export(typeof(Contracts.IInput))]
    public class Plugin : IInput
    {
        public string IsValid()
        {
             return "1";
        }
    }
 }
```

Now, all these produce (two library files and an executable) at the same "bin\Debug" folder.But on executing when reaching the code, "composeParts(this)" an exception occurs like below,

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

When I try to change "Composeparts(container)" there is another exception like below,"

**> The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is

> provided below. Review the CompositionException.Errors property for
>   more detailed information.
>
> 1) Cannot populate the collection
>   'ConsoleApplication2.Program.myinterface' because it does not
>   implement ICollection or is read-only. If the collection is not
>   IEnumerable or T[] it must implement ICollection and be either
>   pre-initialized or be writable with a default constructor.
>
> Resulting in: Cannot activate part 'ConsoleApplication2.Program'
>   Element: ConsoleApplication2.Program -->  ConsoleApplication2.Program **

1. Can you please show me where I am going wrong?
2. I thought both composeparts(this) and composeparts(container) were both same since I use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(). If so, then why did two different exceptions get thrown?

I used importmany like

```
class Program 
 {
    [ImportMany(typeof(Contracts.IInput))]
    public IEnumerable<Contracts.IInput> myinterface { get; set; }

    public void Method()
    {
        var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

        try
        {
            container.ComposeParts(container);
            foreach (var i in myinterface)
                Console.WriteLine(i.IsValid());
        }
        catch (CompositionException compositionException)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(compositionException.ToString());
        }



    }
```

But in this case, still myinterface is null and this throws a null reference exception.

Comment: As Blachshma's way, just change the assemblycatalog to DirectoryCatalog and this example will work!

Comment: Thanks for Blachshma's additional answers. If i understood him correctly, Then these are those points out here:

1. The import statement will do the magic only after Constructor has finished running. 

2. So do not use import statements on properties within a constructor. Hope this helps.

3. And directory catalog looks for dll's inside the specified directory that satisty the import statement.

4. Also, the assembly catalog searches inside the executable's project for any class/properties that satisfy the import statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

First:
Use `Import` not `ImportMany`.

***OR***
Since `ImportMany` expects a collection so you should use something like this:

`public IEnumerable<Contracts.IInput> myinterface { get; set; }`

Second:

Just as you cannot use properties that have the `Import` attribute on them in the Constructor (Thats what an [importing constructor](http://brendanforster.com/mef-import-vs-importingconstructor.html) is for), You can't access them in the program's Main function.

This, for instance, will work:

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
//Add all the parts found in all assemblies in
//the same directory as the executing program

catalog.Catalogs.Add(
                new DirectoryCatalog(
                    Path.GetDirectoryName(
                    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
                    )
                )
            );

var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
container.ComposeParts(container);

// Use the container to get a value for myinterface
myinterface = container.GetExportedValue<Contracts.IInput>();
Console.WriteLine(myinterface.IsValid());
```

Comment: Thanks Blachshma. I tried import. But still i am getting the same exception.

Comment: Yes, I am getting that error when I use import. But now I use the below code with importmany as u suggested. [ImportMany(typeof(Contracts.IInput))]
        public IEnumerable<Contracts.IInput> myinterface { get; set; }

        public void Method()
        {
            var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

            try
            {
                container.ComposeParts(container);
                foreach (var i in myinterface)
                    Console.WriteLine(i.IsValid());
            }

Comment: When I use the above code, it is throwing a null reference exception. "Myinterface" is null..

Comment: I can't read the code, please post it in your question. **Also** the Assembly you want to load to the catalog is the Assembly with the Export not the Assembly with the Import

Comment: And all my assemblies is in the bin\Debug folder. I checked that manually.

Comment: Just found that out by myself Blachshma. Great. Its now working....

+1 for the Directory Catalog. Thank U again. But, why it does not work with new Assemblycatalog() ? Any ideas?

Comment: " Just as you cannot use properties that have the Import attribute on them in the Constructor (Thats what an importing constructor is for), You can't access them in the program's Main function. ".. Sorry I cannot understand this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19081/discussion-between-now-he-who-must-not-be-named-and-blachshma)